# DateTime Format and ToString Format

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim testDate As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue

testDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd")
```

My question is "testDate" which is dateTime type, I did currentDate.ToString() with format and assign this string value without parsing in dateTime type "testDate" variable but its working why and how?

What is the good practice to work with these DateTime formatting things?

Comment: VB.NET is a strongly-typed language. So you can assign String to DateTime type.

Comment: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Turn on Option Strict now and keep it on. This code will not compile with it on. You would have to do an explicit conversion to DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

It works because `Opton Strict` is turned off. This is **very bad**. You need to be using `Option Strict`. Always. It protects you from multiple kinds of serious error.

For example, that code **seems** to work, but it doesn't really do what you think it does, because `DateTime` values like `testDate` don't have a human-readable format at all. The final result of this code is stored in a binary format and only seems to produce the right value because of an additional conversion to string that happens when you output the result.

And speaking of conversions, to get the final value into the `testDate` variable, the code you have first converts the current time to a string, which is culture-sensitive and therefore a surprisingly expensive (read: slow) and error-prone operation. It must then parse the string value back into a DateTime value, which is the reverse of the same slow and error-prone conversion you just did.

But you can skip all that. You want code more like this:

```
Dim testDate As DateTime = DateTime.Today
```

or at least

```
Dim testDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date
```

These produce the same result in a small fraction of the time. They are safer in terms of internationalization issues, avoid all the extra conversions back and forth, are type safe, work with Option Strict enabled, and it's much less overall code to write and maintain.

> What is the good practice to work with these DateTime formatting things?

The thing to understand is you don't worry about format for DateTime values until the last possible moment before showing them to the user. That means not in this code, not saving to a file or database, and not in operations like truncating the time. Wanting to use a string with a DateTime for *anything* but showing the value to a real user or reading a value from a user is a sign something has gone very wrong.

Comment: Joel Coehoorn: Thanks for elaborate explanation.I was surprised when i found it works but it should not without parse to date time.Finally i got the natural behavior by activating the OPTION STRICT.